# Check if a material-table row is still in edit mode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using the [material-table](https://material-table.com) in a [material-ui Stepper](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers) and the user tends to click on "next" button even though the table is still in edit mode. This results in a loss of data.

Can I somehow access the table information to check if the table/row is still in edit mode when the user clicks the "next" button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there's no directly exposed method that would tell you if the table is editable mode or not (and I think there should be), you can still find it out, but you will have to mess a bit with it's internals. First you will need to grab the ref of the table (*find [tableRef](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props) property*) and then the property that will help you is `lastEditingRow` in the state of the table.

So, having `tableRef` that would be: `tableRef.current.state.lastEditingRow`. For a table in editing mode `lastEditingRow` will be set to an object describing the row being edited and `undefined` if table is not in editing mode.

CodeSandbox with example for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-waterfall-lg2ri

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint about the tableRef prop. It perfectly works for me :) I think you should also test if `tableRef.current.state.showAddRow` is false. Otherwise, the user might create a new row, fills out all the details, clicks next without saving and the data is gone.

Comment: Solution worked for me.  I checked not only for `tableRef?.current?.state?.lastEditingRow` but also for `tableRef?.current?.state?.showAddRow` as mentioned by @TomMüller .  This solution passively waits for the user to click the button and then shows an alert. In my case I want to disable the button proactively since it's an OK button on a dialog box. I don't want users thinking they can save when the data is dirty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "useRef callback" and set a state hook, exemple :

```
// Create a state
const [isTableIsEditMode, setIsTableIsEditMode] = useState(false);
// Create a callback
const editRowRef = useCallback((editRow: React.ReactElement<any>) => setIsTableIsEditMode(!!editRow), []);
// Use the call back as a ref in your table for the Edit Row
// the ref is null if the table is not in edit mode
return <MaterialTable
        components={{
            ...
            EditRow: (props) => {
                return <MTableEditRow {...props} ref={editRowRef} />;
            },
        }}
        ...
    />
```

Comment: Worked for adding a new row but for editing a row, the callback was called twice, once with an editRow and once with an undefined editRow.  Consequently, it prevents editing the row.  This is with `"@material-table/core": "^6.1.17"`